# Is it better to separate settings from task tab or to group it?

Tags: layout, settings, wpf

I'm currently developping the v2 of my [bot](http://botforge.net) so i want to redesign the whole UI. As a part of that work, there is one question that i don't achieve to answer myself.

**Is it better to separate settings from task tab or to group the settings with the task related?**

Currently my software is designed like this : 
[image]

You can see that there is a clear separation between the task and the settings related to the task.

Would it be better for the user if each task settings are in the same tab as the task processing controls (start/stop button, stats, infos of the task's progression)..

(wanted to post a paint design of the idea but couldn't due to links restrictions)

What is more convenient for the user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, **users should be able to make changes "in context"**. This also makes clear what setting is being configured. The danger with this approach is adding too many elements to the interface.

**Most applications group settings, so this is a rather established convention.** However, placing settings next to their respective elements is growing in popularity.

**The ideal solution would do both:**

- Place settings of high importance in context.
- Use a Settings or Configure section for options that are less important or not as frequently utilised.